# ¿Cómo ir a una parte de una página externa con framework7?

Tags: html, app, programación-móvil, framework7

Tengo esta estructura.

```
Index
--Lista
----Prodcuto1
----Producto2
----Producto3
```

Para ir del index a la lista de productos uso:

```
<a href="lista.html" class="item-link">
```

Tengo todos los productos en un solo documento html. Pero cuando estoy en la lista quiero poder seleccionar algún producto y que se muestre solo la información del producto.

Se me ocurre que el enlace sería así:

```
<a href="lista.html#productoX" class="item-link">
```

Pero esto no funciona, al menos no en framework7. ¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Así se ve mi código:

```
<li class="list-group-title">A</li>
<li>
    <a href="services.html#page-content2" class="item-link">
        <div class="item-content"> 
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Acetaminofen</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Normalmente recibo respuesta en 12 horas, pero esta vez llevo más de 48 y nada.